# Static vs. non-static helper methods

Tags: php, magento

I'm new to PHP and Magento and am trying to figure out what the difference is between the following two lines:

`$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');`

`$helper = $this->helper('catalog/category');`

I've seen similar code in the template file, but when and why would I use one instead of the other?

Comment: You may want to read up on [static methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line `$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');` is assigning an object to helper.

The second line `$helper = $this->helper('catalog/categry');` is assigning a property of an object to a variable - but can only be used WITHIN the object as it uses the `$this->` syntax.

Inside an object refer to it's properties by `$this->` while outside, refer to it via the variable name, then the property `$someVar->`.

The other thing to note is that your first statement is (as Eric correctly points out) is that the first can be a call to a static method (which is a lovely way to have an object function run without creating an instance of the object - which normally doesn't work).

Normally you have to create an object before you can use it:

```
class something
{
    public $someProperty="Castle";
    public static $my_static = 'foo';
}

echo $this->someProperty; // Error. Non-object. Using '$this->' outside of scope.

echo something::$someProperty; // Error. Non Static.
echo something::$my_static; // Works! Because the property is define as static.

$someVar = new something();

echo $someVar->someProperty; // Output: Castle
```

Comment: @down Noppers. Have a look at [example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) in this link for a fair bit more detail and examples.

Comment: `something::$my_static;` or `something::my_static;`?

Comment: @AlexLunix From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) `print $foo::$my_static . "\n";`

Comment: @AlexLunix if you want to call with something::my_static; assign my_static with const variable

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano I only asked because non static variables are called without the $.